# Technical architecture of platform on .Net Core

Tags: design, .net-core

I'm designing a platform that will run robots developed by others.

Basically anyone could implement a `IAutonomousAgent` and register the implementation on the platform. At runtime, the platform will identify the available implementations, load the code, instantiate and run the robots.

One thing that I have to be able to control is the very life of the robot. For instance it would be the responsibility of the platform to kill robots that have become unresponsive. And that is the catch.

The platform cannot rely on the good faith of the robot to acknowledge that the CancellationToken has been received and stop.

.Net Core does not have a Task.Kill method.

I could encapsulate the operation on a `Thread` but .Net Core does not implement `Thread.Abort`.

I considered to run the robots on a separated processes. I discarded it because 1. either the user would need to implement a whole program (instead of only a interface) or I would have to dynamically compile the code onto a program. All this because you can't just run a isolated piece of code. 2. The platform would provide several services in form of events, which would have to be reengineered to work across processes. 3. The platform would have a finer grain of control over the robot health via a `healthcheck` method. This over IPC would be harder.

So, my question is: what can I do to guarantee that I will be able to communicate-to and kill a robot?

Comment: That's a fun question. Sounds similar trying to "kill" a Java thread. But before we even get to killing the 'robot',  I would be concerned about how to sandbox the uploaded code. The two questions are related, in that decisions made for one can affect the other quite a bit. Is there enough isolation and ability to kill in .Net's AppDomain feature?

Comment: At first glance, after years away from .Net, I'd say it's either investigate AppDomain, see if it fits the requirements or run the robots as separate processes with limited rights, or in docker or similar containers with limited rights. On linux you could look at  running them in linux containers of your own construction. I don't know what the windows equivalent would be. But you should choose an isolation technique, and it will likely answer your kill question.

Comment: Regarding the isolation, I know it will be an issue, but I decide to tackle the problems one at a time

Comment: Have you considered running each robot in a separate process instead of a separate thread?  It makes IPC more difficult, but it could help both on the sandboxing side of things and on the 'killing' side as well.

Comment: @EricPetroelje I just detailed why I discarded the "new process" approach on the question, pls check it out

Comment: For the part about re-engineering the event system, I totally agree with you - that's just going to be harder to handle across processes.  As for requiring bots to have their own program (i.e. Main() method) that shouldn't be necessary - you would write the executable "bootstrapper" program yourself, use it to load up the bot dll and call into whatever methods it implements.  You would probably also use that bootstrapper code to hook into whatever IPC method you are implementing.

Comment: @Leonardo One at a time is good. In this case, as someone who has built this kind of thing before, I'd suggest doing isolation first. You'll likely find that if you solve isolation, the kill solution is right there looking at you. If I knew .Net as well as I know Java I'd say pursuing the kill thread is a dead end where you would have to do better than the people who built the JVM and the whole community to solve it. But this is .Net, and with AppDomains there appears to be an avenue to safely kill.

Comment: I haven't tried doing this kind of solution in .NET Core. In .NET Framework, yeah, you would use AppDomain. As far as I can tell in .NET Core, you can extend the class `AssemblyLoadContext`, use the protected ctor overload that sets `IsCollectible` to true, and then you can use `Load` and `Unload`. By the way, do not reuse it, you want the `AssemblyLoadContext` to be garbage collected. What you need is a library (created by the user or compiled by you), you can do type discovery (reflection) on it and call what you need. Your code that uses the `AssemblyLoadContext` would delegates the events.

Comment: LOL - At first the question read "platform kill robots" and I thought "oh my goodness, what is this person doing?" It's been a long day. I edited the question to read "platform **to** kill robots" I think I liked the question better the other way, though. :) We definitely don't have enough "kill robot" discussions on this site.

Comment: I don't think AppDomains are going to work in .net core. They are more limited. You're probably going to need to use a separate process.